# Vertical padding is larger than horizontal padding

Tags: html, css

I have a file with the following structure:

```css
body {
  font-family: font;
  font-size: small;
  margin: 0px;
}
#main {
  font-size: 105%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>heading</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the padding and margin are set to be the same on all sides. But the vertical paddings(bottom AND top) look obviously larger than the horizontal paddings. Why?

Comment: Looks fine to me when I check the elements in the inspector. Are you trying to center something?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: As a guess, you're not taking into consideration that the heading and paragraph may have margins that you haven't reset.

Comment: Have you taken into account the margin / padding of the h1 and p elements?

Comment: Try putting some background color or something so we might have a context of what it should look like to you. They look exactly the same in the inspector in Chrome.

Comment: I set the default margin of h1 and p to 0 and problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the default browser styles for h1 and p tags

```
h1, p {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
  font-family: font;
  font-size: small;
  margin: 0px;
}
#main {
  font-size: 105%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks. I set the margin to 0 in the body, and I thought that would set the margin of all elements in the body to 0. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Body is an element by itself, you would have to do something like `body *` to get all the elements inside the body tag to have the styles

Answer (score 0):

There are default vertical margins around `<h1>` and `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your h1 tag has (by default) a bit of top margin. Add this code to your css to fix it:

```
h1 {margin-top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/

Div elements automatically a blank space before and after. Refer to fiddle to see the result of taking the div element away and adding classes to the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't target the `h1` and the `p` tag; you targetted `#main` and the `body`. This is also why the `font-size` isn't as it should.

The standard rules are now stronger/more important than the inherited rules.

You can simply fix it. Directly target the `h1` and the `p` and future elements, write `!important` behing every rule or target everything inside `#main` or `body` like this:

```
body {
  font-family: font;
  font-size: small;
  margin: 0px;
}
#main > *{
  font-size: 105%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```